How to get offset in Assembly (Intel 8086)?
I have a problem with Assembly code. I need to put the offset variable wordl1p into the BX register and copy the contents of the second byte (the high-order byte) of the wordl1p variable into the variable bytes2n. I have to use indirect addressing via the contents of the BX register Here is my current code:
cpu 8086
segment code
        mov ax, data         
        mov ds, ax            
        mov ax, 14487         
        mov [wordl1p], ax    
        mov bx, wordl1p

        mov byte [bx + 2], 116 
    
        mov al, [bx + 1] 
        mov bytes2n, al
    
        int 21h              
        hlt
    
segment data
    bytes2n db 15             
    wordl1p dw 1234  


What assembler are you using?  Is this NASM?  If so, mov bx, wordl1p.  If MASM or TASM, mov bx, offset wordl1p.   Your mov byte [bx + 2], 116 looks like NASM syntax, storing to one byte past the end of wordl1p.  In MASM syntax, you'd need byte ptr instead of byte.  But mov bytes2n, al isn't valid NASM syntax, that's trying to mov to an immediate constant.  In NASM, you always need square brackets around something to make it a memory reference with that address.

@PeterCordes I am using NASM and I know that mov bytes2n, al is not valid but I do not know what is the correct way how to write it

Like I said, you need square brackets around it, mov [bytes2n], al.  The register operand implies the byte operand-size.
